# How to prevent the dropped element from being draggable again - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can i prevent the element which is dragged and dropped to a particular place from being re-dragged within the droppable area i'm using jquery ui.

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/DTYEB/

In above example element can be dragged into dropbox but the element can be re-dragged within the box is it possible to prevent this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply a callback function to the `revert` option, and set the `disabled` option to `true` if the draggable was dropped in a valid location:

```
$('#imageContainer div').draggable({  
    grid : [20,20],                
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: function(valid) {
        if(valid) {
            this.draggable("option", "disabled", true);   
        }
        return !valid;
    }
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTYEB/17/).

This functionality does not seem to be in the jQuery UI documentation. It states that the `revert` value should be a boolean or a string, but doesn't mention that it can be a function too. This came up in another question yesterday, and I wrote a [short article](http://www.jamesallardice.com/2012/02/16/run-a-callback-function-when-a-jquery-ui-draggable-widget-reverts/) detailing the use of this callback function which will explain it further if you're interested.